# Accentuation Jar File on Console

Tags: java

I've compiled a java program as Runnable Jar File in eclipse. But when I run it on the console I get:

```
configura��o
```

instead of

```
configuração
```

What am I missing to get the input as I see it in eclipse?

PS: It's not a console problem

Regards

Comment: This is obviously an encoding issue from the console you are using - I guess you are trying to execute the jar on a windows command line which defaults to windows-1252 (Cp1252 or ANSI) instead of UTF-8 which Eclipse is using

Comment: I'm using mac and iTerm console.
LANG="pt_PT.UTF-8"